# Python testing - multiple `tox` environments with parallel runs and coverage reporting

Tags: python, unit-testing, parallel-processing, coverage.py

I'm having a hard time figuring out a configuration for Python unit testing that combines:

1. Multiple environments (specifying e.g. versions of python or dependency packages) given as `tox` environments
2. Parallel running of the `tox` environments, for speed (some things being tested take a while to run)
3. Reporting of test coverage

I've tried using a `tox.ini` file like the following (and then running it with `python -m tox --parallel=auto`), but I can't figure out how to do the `combine` step at the end, rather than in each environment:

```
[tox]
envlist = py{38,39}-more_itertools{812,813,814}

[testenv]
deps = pytest
       coverage
       more_itertools812: more_itertools>=8.12,<8.13
       more_itertools813: more_itertools>=8.13,<8.14
       more_itertools814: more_itertools>=8.14,<8.15
commands = python -m coverage run --parallel -m pytest
           python -m coverage combine
           python -m coverage xml
           python -m coverage html
```

If I don't use `--parallel` inside the `commands` section, all the environments try to write to the same `.coverage` file, and they hit various race conditions, causing death. (I opened [a ticket for this](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/1514).)

I'm trying to avoid a solution that requires post-processing after running `tox`, if possible.  Not sure if that's possible.

I need to support both `pytest` and `unittest` based test suites, FWIW.  Not sure if that rules out using [`pytest-cov`](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/) or not, but I've also seen the above race condition happening if I use `commands = python -m pytest --cov=.` in my `tox.ini`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up [environment dependencies](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#depends). See the example in the pytest-cov docs: https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tox.html

```
[tox]
envlist = 
    clean
    py{38,39}-more_itertools{812,813,814}
    report

[testenv]
...
commands = python -m coverage run --parallel -m pytest
depends =
    clean: py38,py39
    py38,py39: report

[testenv:clean]
deps = coverage
skip_install = true
commands = -coverage erase

[testenv:report]
deps = coverage
skip_install = true
commands =
    -coverage combine
    -coverage report
    -coverage html
```